# Почему ActiveModel::Serializer не сериализует вложенный массив

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails

У меня есть две модели Post и Tag.

```
  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name",       null: false
    t.text     "text",       null: false
    t.string   "permalink",  null: false
    t.string   "images"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "tags", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "tag_name", null: false
  end
```

А также сериалайзеры:

```
class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :text, :permalink, :images, :created_at

  has_many :tags
end
```

и:

```
class TagSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  type :tag
  attribute :tag_name, key: :'tag-name'
  has_many :posts

end
```

Сериалайзеры работают с адептером json_api.
Метод в контроллере, который возвращает список постов выглядит так:

```
  def index
    @posts = Post.sorted
    render json: @posts, include: ['tags']
  end
```

Но получаю вот такой JSON:

[image: Тэги]

А хотелось бы, чтобы тэги тоже проходили через serializer, и я мог увидеть tag_name (точнее tag-name, по канону json-api). Гуглил, советовали прописать в config/initializers/active_model_serializers.rb строчку

```
ActiveModel::Serializer.config.default_includes = '**'
```

Но не помогло.
Gemfile:

```
...
gem 'active_model_serializers', github: 'rails-api/active_model_serializers'
...
```

rails 5.0.2
ruby 2.3.1

Как добавить сериализацию для связанных объектов? И возможно ли это?